# OpenRedirect Prevention Through $sceDelegateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The $sceDelegateProvider documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider states that you can use the resourceUrlBlacklist to block open directs.

From my understanding, the $sceDelegateProvider is only used for when you render templates, from the such of ng-include, and it does stop loading those resources if you include them in the blacklist.

The confusing part to me is their documentation looks like this:

**Example**: Consider the following case.

- your app is hosted at url http://myapp.example.com/
- but some of yourtemplates are hosted on other domains you control such as
  http://srv01.assets.example.com/, http://srv02.assets.example.com/,
  etc.
- and you have an open redirect at http://myapp.example.com/clickThru?....*

Their example looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self',
    // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
    'http://srv*.assets.example.com/**'
  ]);

  // The blacklist overrides the whitelist so the open redirect here is blocked.
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist([
    'http://myapp.example.com/clickThru**'
  ]);
});
```

The way you generally do redirections in AngularJS is through the $window.location.href which could enable someone to do an open redirect if implemented incorrectly.

I have created a sample application to reflect what I feel this should look like: http://plnkr.co/edit/cjXsCVcRGwgtgqZr13mE?p=preview

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example85-production</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Redirect Example</h1>
    <p>Why doesn't this work?.</p>

    <h2>Demo</h2>
    <div>
        <h3>redirect</h3>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
        <ul>
            <li >
                <a href="/redirect?url=https://angularjs.org">
                    AngularJS (https)
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/redirect?url=http://angularjs.org">
                    AngularJS (http)
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
// script.js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [
            'ngSanitize',
            'ngRoute'
        ]);
})();

// app.config.js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(function ( $sceDelegateProvider, $routeProvider ) {
      $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
      // Allow same origin resource loads.
        'self',
        // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
        'http://srv*.assets.example.com/**'
      ]);

      // The blacklist overrides the whitelist so the open redirect here is blocked.
      $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist([
        'http://example.com/redirect?url=https://angularjs.org',
        'http://example.com/redirect?url=http://angularjs.org'
      ]);

            $routeProvider
                .when('/redirect', {
                    template: '<em>redirecting',
                    controller: function ($scope, $location,$window) {
                        $scope.url = $location.$$search['url'];
                        $window.location.href = $scope.url;
                    }
        })
            }
        );
})();
```

Can anyone give me some clarity if the documentation means something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question...

The $sceDelegateProvider is not used to prevent redirects when using $location and $window. The $sceDelegateProvider is strictly used when loading templates for ngRoute, directives, ngSrc, ngInclude, etc, and is only checked against the initial URL, not the final target.

For example if you whitelist facebook.com and it contains a redirect to a page that's not whitelisted, such as malicious.com, it will still load successfully as long as it's approved by the CORS policy of malicious.com.

Answer (score 1):

$sceDelegateProvider only sandboxes template url resolution and open redirects that occur in the process. For instance, if you `ng-include` a whitelisted resource that 301 redirects to another resource that **isn't** whitelisted, it gets rejected.

It won't meddle with $window.location (or $location).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the $window and $location, i did  know this but it just seemed to be the only thing I could think of. 

Sadly this isn't correct, I created a PoC; if you whitelist a URL and it contains a redirect and even if that redirected url is in the blacklist or not included in the whitelist; the page will load as long as CORS is enabled (I believe this is intended as you have whitelisted the previous page). 

I'm going with the result is, if you have a open redirect in your website and you know about it, you can take measures in blacklisting access to that page.